# Is there a way to specify either max height or max width for an image?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

Is there anyway to maintain following aspect ratio with either maximum width or maximum height, below are the situations I'm facing.
maximum width or height should be 500px

```
400x300 image - no resizing (both sides below 500 maximum size)
500x500 image - no resizing (both sides at exactly 500 maximum size).
600x400 image - resize to 500x333 (preserves same ratio) as one side is over 500 pixels.
1000x1200 image -resize to 417x500 (preserves same ratio), as both sides are over 500 pixels
```

Comment: CSS `max-height: 500px; max-width: 500px;`? Or are you after something more complex? (In which case, you may need to expand your question)

Comment: What about this 1000x1200 image -resize to 417x500 (preserves same ratio), according to max-height:500px and max-width:500px, for that image having resolution 1000*1200 will have 500*500 , I don't want this, I also want to maintain aspect ratio, the height would be 500px in this case and width would be calculated.

Comment: That would happen if you set their `width` and `height`, but using `max-width` and `max-height` can maintain the aspect ratio. I've added an answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Just another thought, if you're not using the original bigger size anywhere (in case the image is bigger than 500px), you should resize the image to process and load faster and use less space.

Comment: Yes, It's good to resize , thanks for the suggestion  @EdsonHoracioJunior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the CSS properties `max-width` and `max-height` to limiting values, while leaving the image with `auto` for it's `width` and `height` can be used to maintain aspect ratio while restricting the max size like this:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x100" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x500" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x200" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x1000" />
```

The images larger than 500px will be resized to fit the limit, while smaller images will retain their original size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm just testing this.